$f(f(x))=g(g(x))$ but $f$ and $g$ are different
Let $f,g:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be strictly increasing bijective functions such that $f(f(x)) = g(g(x))$. Is it neccesary that $f=g$?
What we have tried:
We started with the case of $g(x)=x$, In this case the answer turns out to be yes. As if for some $x$ we have $f(x) \neq x$, lets assume WLOG(as the other case has the same proof) that $f(x)>x$ then as $f$ is increasing we get $f(f(x))>f(x)$ and so $x>f(x)$ which is a contradiction.
But it turns out to be an oversimplification as if we try the same thing we get $f(x)>g(x)$ and then $f(f(x))>f(g(x))$ so $g(g(x))>f(g(x))$ which is not a contradiction.
It does give us a point $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)=g(x_1)$ as $f,g$ has to be continous, and then we thought to repeat the same argument In the sub Interval $[0,x_1]$ and $[x_1,1]$ and then reqursivly construct a dense set in wich they are equal and finish from continouty but it turns out in falls exactly because we don't have $g(x_1)=x_1$ indeed if we assume that for all $x \in [0,x_1]$ we have $f(x) \neq g(x)$ from continouty lets assume $f(x)>g(x)$ then put $f$ on the inequaloty to get $f(f(x))>f(g(x))$ and so $g(g(x))>f(g(x))$ and then we want to say contridiction but we don't have $g(x) \in [0,x_1]$ exactly because $g(x_1)$ might be bigger then $x_1$ and so the argument falls.
another Idea that didn't get anywhere was to notice that $f^{(2n)}=g^{(2n)}$ for all $n$ and then somehow take a limit and get something from it

Did you try an example?

yes we disscused it at length but we don't know. It needs to be increasing and thus continous and injective so it makes in quiite hard(for us at least)

not increasing. Please read the question before downvoting.

Not sure if it's equivalent, but setting $g(x) = x$ would simplify things. Is there an increasing bijection $f$ such that $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$, but $f(x) \neq x$ for some $x$?

@MatthewLeingang we got that the only $f$ like that is the identity. Indeed if $f(x)>x$ then as $f$ is increasing we get $f(f(x))>f(x)$ so $x>f(x)$ contradictin(for $f(x)<x$ its the same). So we think its an oversimplification as we didint mange to do the same for the general case

You are assuming "strictly" increasing then? Suppose $$ is strictly increasing, $(())=$ and $()≠$ for some $$. Then there's some $∈[0,1]$ such that $()≠$. Then $()<⟺=(())<()$.

@DietrichBurde sorry I am not an english speaker and thougt that increasing is stringer then monotonic increasing

@DietrichBurde But nonstricly increasing functions cannot be injective.

@DietrichBurde in any case the question is not $f(f(x))=x$

@DietrichBurde We don't see why this assumption can be done can you alaborate?

@RT1 In order to prevent the question from being closed, it may help to add your own thoughts to the post (not just in the comments). Apparently you already put some work into that problem.

@RT1: this is a really nice question with a nice answer. It has been closed just because you didn't say anything about your work on the question, except in comments. Please edit the question to add some more context so that it can be reopened.

@RobArthan I added what we tried

I'll take $f(x) = x^2$.  Define $x_n$ for integers $n$ such that $x_0 = 1/2$, $x_{n+1} = x_n^2$ and $x_{n-1} = \sqrt{x_n}$.  Thus $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$ and $x_n \to 1$ as $n \to -\infty$, and $f$ maps $[x_{n+1}, x_n]$ one-to-one onto $[x_{n+2},x_{n+1}]$.  Take any other increasing continuous function $g$ from $[x_1, x_0]$ onto $[x_2, x_1]$, and then extend it to the rest of $[0,1]$ as follows. Once $g$ is defined on $[x_{n+1}, x_n]$, we can define it on $[x_{n+2},x_{n+1}] = g([x_{n+1},x_n])$ by $g(x) = f(f(g^{-1}(x))$, or on
$[x_n, x_{n-1}] = g^{-1}([x_{n+1},x_n])$ by $g(x) = g^{-1}(f(f(x)))$.

So $x_n = 2^{-2^n}$

To completely define $g$ we should also say $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$, an obvious requirement but not covered by the recursive intervals part.

Beautiful solution (+)
